# Таблица лидеров в приложении Android

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play-services, google-play-games

Столкнулся с проблемой, что по документиции гугл вставил все правильно, но таблица лидеров не отображается, хотя в аккаунт google play заходит, после чего немного думает и обратно отправляет в игру. Возможно где то с кодом ошибся.

```
private string leaderboard = "CgkI9pfnzM8FEAIQAQ";
        void Start()
        {
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
        Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
                            if (success) {
                                Debug.Log ("You have successefully loged in");
                            } else {
                                Debug.Log ("Login failded");
                            }

                        });
        }
    LeaderboardOn()
    {
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI (leaderboard);
    }
    Hightscore()
{
if(score>highscore){
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Highscore", score);
            gameOverHighScoreText.GetComponent<Text>().text ="HIGHSCORE:"+score.ToString ();
            Social.ReportScore (score, leaderboard, (bool success) => {
                if (success) print("Successefully added to Leaderboard");
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI(leaderboard );`.

Comment: @Suvitruf если это не решило проблему, где еще может быть ошибка?

Comment: У вас дебаг логи выводят? Там должны быть довольно подробные логи.